# document.click() on a document

Tags: javascript, html, dom, dom-events

DOM button is getting clicked with `.click()` method, but its not working on document itself.

```js
/* Working fine */
function getAlert() {
    alert("Clicked!!!");
}
var btn = document.getElementById('btn');
btn.onclick = getAlert;
btn.click()

/* Should be work  */
document.onclick = getAlert;
document.clicked()
```

```html
<button id="btn">Click Me!</button>
```

Please help.

Comment: `document.getElementById('btn');` this id is not found in the document.

Comment: Your attempt at providing a [mcve] demonstrates a number of problems which have nothing to do with the question you are asking. Please **test** your MCVEs to make sure they are a suitable demonstration of the actual problem you are having.

Answer (score 7):

`document` objects are not things that can be clicked on.

Event handlers can be bound to a `document`, and events will bubble until they reach the `document` and trigger a handler, but you can't click directly on the `document`.

Answer (score 6):

`document.getElementById('btn')` this id is not found in the document, So please add the element id and remove `document.clicked()` because its not a function on document object.

Here you may please check the working code snippet.

```js
/* Working fine */
function getAlert() {
    alert("Clicked!!!");
}
var btn = document.getElementById('btn');
btn.onclick = getAlert;
btn.click()

/* Should be work  */
document.onclick = getAlert;
//document.clicked()
```

```html
<button id="btn">Click Me!</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

As Quentin already explains in his answer, a `document` object cannot be clicked upon.

Event handlers associated on `document` execute due to the events bubbling up the DOM. For example, a click event on the button in your snippet traverses the button -> then body -> then document.

So, as an alternative to `document.clicked()` you attempt in your question, you can trigger the event on `body` element via, `document.body.click()`.

```js
/* Working fine */
function getAlert() {
    alert("Clicked!!!");
}
var btn = document.getElementById('btn');
btn.onclick = getAlert;
btn.click()

/* Should be work  */
document.onclick = getAlert;
document.body.click()
```

```html
<button id="btn">Click Me!</button>
```

You can read more about event bubbling here: [What is event bubbling and capturing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616694/what-is-event-bubbling-and-capturing#4616720)

---

Note: I have added ID attribute to the button in your snippet to ensure that it runs.

Answer (score -1):

you can do this with jquery like this:

```
$(document).on('click', ()=>{console.log('clicked')})

$(document).click()
```

Comment: Adding an entire library for the sake of a simple button click is very much discouraged.

Comment: @luk2302 Hi might be already using this, in his project, so its not being added for the sake of a button click, so this is just a possible answer to this question.

Comment: No, this is not a proper answer. If you suspect OP is using jQuery ask for assurance in a comment, don't just post an answer assuming that he is. Shall I post an answer that enables click listeners for EVERY js library I know?

Comment: @luk2302 should I remove this answer then?